# How can i use awk command in csv files

Tags: shell, csv, wildcard

in our csv names contain year,month,date,hour, minutes like: abc_202002111500.csv
so we have many csv files for every time.

if i want to search the number that 1234 in december 02 2020 at  between 15:00 -15:59;

```
awk -F"|" '{if ($3 == 1234) print $5}' abc_2020021115*.csv
```

So what if i want to write same number same date but between 15:00 -17:00 ?

```
awk -F"|" '{if ($3 == 1234) print $5}' abc_20200211?????.csv
```

Comment: The wildcards in the filename are interpreted by the command shell, not by awk. Please edit your question, specify which command shell you are using. Also adjust the tags accordingly.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with awk - you're asking how to identify specific files in shell using globbing. That fact that you're passing those file names to awk is completely irrelevant, you could be passing them to cat, grep, or any other command.

Answer (score 2):

The answer relies on a feature of most shells, search for `shell wildcard range` for details.

In your case, instead of `abc_2020021115*.csv`, use `abc_202002111[56]*.csv`

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do file-filtering in `GNU AWK` you might harness [BEGINFILE](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE.html) and [nextfile](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nextfile-Statement.html) for that.